# Text becomes invisible behind background canvas Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine

I just added 3D Text on my scene and it is invisible on the background of Canvas, that is "Render Mode: Screen Space - Camera". How i can make it visible on background of my canvas?

[image: Text is invisible]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are 2 ways to fix this:

1. Change the Sorting Layer of the obstructing object or the Order in Layer of the obstructing object to be lower than that of the canvas.

OR

2. Make a new canvas, and assign it a new Sorting Layer that is above all other existing Sorting Layers. Move any text you want into the new canvas.

As an example for #2, here I have my normal text in a lower canvas, but I created an overlay canvas for text that absolutely must go above everything else.

[image]

I find that the second solution is a better general solution for the issue, as in the first solution you have to change the layers for every object in the scene that might obstruct your text.

Comment: This looks like a correct solution to me, and should be marked as such.